# nested attributes excel import in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my params likes,

```
params.require(:subject).permit(:id, :org_id, :subject_id, :subject_name, :subject_desc,
                           :subject_color, subject_modules_attributes: [:id, :subject_module_id, :subject_id,
                           :module_number, :module_name, :_destroy,
                           module_details_attributes: [:id, :module_detail_id, :subject_module_id,
                             :module_detail_number, :description, :_destroy]])
```

I want to save data in 3 tables by importing one excel file. How it is possible using roo gem

```
def self.import(file)
     allowed_attributes = ["org_id", "subject_name", "subject_desc","subject_color",
                            subject_modules_attributes: ["org_id", "standard_id", "subject_id", "module_number", "module_name"],
                            module_details_attributes: ["subject_module_id", "module_detail_number", "description"]]
    Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      subject = new
      subject.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*allowed_attributes)
      subject.save!
    end 
end
```

I saved data first table but in nested parameters could not save 2nd and 3rd tables as subject_modules and module_details. How can I modify my code to get the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modify my codes and give create method to each table like,

```
@subject = Subject.create(my fields...)
@sub_mod = SubjectModule.create(my fields...)
@mod_det = ModuleDetail.create(my fields...)
```

And specify the spreadsheet column for the corresponding fields.
Thanks.